# A While-Loop with MySql 5.7 where is my fault?

Tags: mysql, sql, while-loop

My first Question here, so "Hello world" ;) Hope I can give some help back one day.
Here my Problem, first my SQL-Query:
Do I need putting this While Loop in a procedure? Actually I wanted to build a nested Loop (actually a for - Loop). This techniques in SQL are new for me. So i want to try first a small example like this above. But after some changes there more faults than ever :) . I've tried to follow the information from the manual.. but no chance.
Where is my fault?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dowhile()
    BEGIN
        DECLARE j INT DEFAULT 1;
        DECLARE j_total INT DEFAULT 10;


    WHILE j < j_total DO
        SELECT TOP 1 * FROM `collection_dates` WHERE `ortsnummer` = j AND `pid` = '1' ORDER 
        BY `termin_date` ASC;
        SET j = j + 1;
    END WHILE;
END

CALL dowhile();
```

---

Errors:

```
[FEHLER in Abfrage 1] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3
[FEHLER in Abfrage 2] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE j_total INT DEFAULT 10' at line 1
[FEHLER in Abfrage 3] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHILE j < j_total DO
            SELECT TOP 1 * FROM `collection_dates` WHERE `ortsnummer' at line 1
[FEHLER in Abfrage 4] Unknown system variable 'j'
```

Comment: You don't appear to be setting delimiters.

Answer (score 2):

MYSQL has no TOP is uses LIMIT for that purpose

DELIMITER has to be add, if you run this in a query tab

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE dowhile() 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE j INT DEFAULT 1; DECLARE j_total INT DEFAULT 10;

    WHILE j < j_total DO
        SELECT * FROM `collection_dates` WHERE `ortsnummer` = j AND `pid` = '1' ORDER 
        BY `termin_date` ASC LIMIT 1;
        SET j = j + 1;
    END WHILE;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank you! But, I need to call the procedure outside of the Delimiter, isn't it? But if I do so, then there is an error: PROCEDURE database.dowhile does not exist

Comment: I run the code and it inserts a stored procedure, else it would give an error. before calling the procedure run the code. You can do that in a query tab, or use create procedure

Comment: Missing delimiter on the end statement?

Comment: DELIMITER is set. I work with Sequel Pro. So I can mark the code and execute it. Error here: Query was empty After that I call the Procedure, but then the procedure doesn't exist. I also tried now just execute the while Loop without a procedure like:     DELIMITER //

    BEGIN
     DECLARE j INT DEFAULT 1;
     DECLARE j_total INT DEFAULT 2;
    
     WHILE j < j_total DO
   SELECT * FROM `collection_dates` WHERE `ortsnummer` = j AND `pid` = '1' ORDER BY `termin_date` ASC LIMIT 1;
   SET j = j + 1;
  END WHILE;
 END
 DELIMITER ;       but here also: Query was empty

Comment: you can check here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/27Rv4Jz8CEm7r8TxYLVfC6/4  it works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `while` loop for this query at all.  A much more efficient way to write it is:

```
select cd.*
from (select cd.*,
             row_number() over (partition by ortsnummer order by termin_date asc) as seqnum
      from collection_dates cd
      where pid = 1 and ortsnummer between 1 and 10
     ) cd
where seqnum = 1;
```

Or, alternatively, using a correlated subquery:

```
select cd.*
from collection_dates cd
where cd.pid = 1 and cd.ortsnummer between 1 and 10 and
      cd.termin_date = (select min(cd2.termin_date)
                        from collection_dates cd2
                        where cd2.pid = cd.pid and
                              cd2.ortsnummer = cd.ortsnummer
                       );
```

Note that this version assumes that the date is unique for the combination of the other two columns.  With an index on `(pid, ortsnummer, termin_date)` this is probably the faster method.

When using SQL, you should avoid while loops (and cursors) unless you have a really good reason for using them.  Your query is not a good reason.